# Build Debian/Ubuntu package based off package control source

Tags: packaging, deb, dh-make

The Bitcoin source code contains a debian package control package folder which can be used to make a package.

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/tree/master/contrib/debian

Just wondering what the best tool to use to build a package from this?

Answer (score 0):

Building software is usually done by following the developers instructions usually provided in `README` or `INSTALL`, but since that would make everybody's life so much easier devs often don't provide such information. You should open an issue on github.com and request it. Since this is obviously (haha) a Debian package, you can follow https://debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/build.en.html to build it.